# How to get CGImageForProposedRect to provide 1:1 pixel data on Retina Mac

Tags: macos, nsimage, cgimage

In our app, we're creating an PDF `NSImage` (therefore scalable) and then using `CGImage` routines to write that data to a TIFF file.  This works fine on non-retina display Macintoshes, but on retina machines, the data that is returned is twice the resolution we expect (just like the screen).

The code we're using works takes a newly formed `NSView` subclass referencing the data to draw (not the original on-screen view) as printingMapView.

```
NSData *pdfData = [printingMapView dataWithPDFInsideRect: frame];

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData: pdfData];
[image setSize: size];

NSRect pRect = NSMakeRect( 0, 0, [image size].width, [image size].height);

CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImageForProposedRect: &pRect context: NULL hints:NULL];
```

I have looked around for any hints that could be handed to the `CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints` call, but there's nothing in the Apple documentation relating to content scale.

Is there any way to do this other than creating an `NSBitmapImageRep` of the full size and passing that in as the `context` parameter to `CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints`?

That seems like it's likely to use a lot of memory during the operation.

Comment: any luck on that?

Comment: @PeterLapisu No. I went ahead and used the NSBitmapImageRep as described in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

So CGImageForProposedRect does return 1:1 pixel data, if you are getting a CGImage out of the function that is doubled in size the NSImageRep of that NSImage must also be doubled in size. Check your code to see if you have any calls to NSImage drawInRect where you are writing to an  retina context. That is what was happening to me.

Comment: As described above, that is what is happening, and I understand that.  The question was specifically whether there was any way to get non-retina data without having to create a full-sized bitmap context off screen to draw into.